# How to hide the toolbar when user taps an action in a CNContactViewController?

Tags: ios, ios9

This just started happening with iOS 9.

I have a CNContactViewController that displays a contact for the user to edit and save. I also have toolbar buttons at the bottom of the screen by calling setToolbarItems.

The problem is that when the user taps "Add To Existing Contact", the toolbar buttons stay on the screen and cover the bottom of the contact list that shows up, so the last contact on the list can't be tapped.

Similarly if "Share Contact" is tapped, the toolbar buttons cover most of the "Cancel" button, so the word Cancel can't be read and it's hard to tap.

Is there a notification I can use to know when to hide the toolbar buttons?

Comment: Have you looked at the CNContactViewController's hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property?

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the tip. It doesn't seem to work though. The CNContactViewController needs the bottom toolbar, and it works fine. It's the new viewcontroller that pops up when the "Add To Existing Contact" button is pushed that needs to have NO toolbar. Is there a way to be notified when a new viewcontroller gets displayed?

Comment: Please share some code. How are you configuring and presenting your CNContactViewController?